# Remove clicks from background layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 Relative Layouts(A,B and C) and parent of all these layouts is same(which is also a Relative Layout). Layout 'A' has fill_parent to its parent and other two(B and C) are on the first layout(Layout 'A').'B' aligned to top and 'C' aligned to bottom relative to 'A'. So when I touch on layout 'B' or 'C' the touchListener of Layout 'A' gets called.

So how to remove touchListener of layout 'A' when user tap on the 'B' or 'C'. I mean to say nothing happened when user tap on 'B' or 'C'

Comment: Post your code here please, we will get shorted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my own question is :

```
B.setClickable(true);
C.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

> So how to remove touchListener of layout 'A' when user tap on the 'B' or 'C'. I mean to say nothing happened when user tap on 'B' or 'C'

In the onClick event of B and C, you can do:

```
layoutA.setOnTouchListener(null); // if you have set the touch listener as you mentioned in above quote.
```

In case you have set the onClickListener, then do:

```
 layoutA.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Comment: Not working. I found the solution please see my answer to this post

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
        relativeLayoutA.bringToFront();
        relativeLayoutB.bringToFront();
```

Comment: Not working. I found the solution please see my answer to this post